# Tensor product between a representation and its dual

Tags: representation-theory, characters

If $\chi$ is the character of an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ such that $\chi(1) > 1$, then I want to prove $\chi \chi^{*}$ is never irreducible.

My idea was to show $\sum_{g \in G}| \chi(g) |^4 > |G|$. However i can not find a suitable way following this idea.

Any hints?

Comment: Show that $\chi\chi^*$ always has the trivial character as a constituent.

Comment: So, since $| \chi(1) |^{2} >1$ and $(\chi \chi^{*},\chi_{triv})_{G} = \dfrac{\sum_{g \in G} | \chi(g)|^{2}}{|G|} \in \mathbb{N} $ then $(\chi \chi^{*},\chi_{triv})_{G} >= 1$?

Comment: Exactly${}{}{{}}$!

Comment: Easier than it looks, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that $M\otimes M^*\cong \mathrm{End(M)}$. Can you spot any submodules?

Comment: I thought $<v_i \otimes v_i^{*}>, \, i=1, \dots , \chi(1)$ but i don’t know how to prove it is G-stable

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959301/g-representations-w-otimes-v-to-texthomv-w) it is shown that under the isomorphism $M\otimes M^*\cong \mathrm{End}(M)$, $G$ acts on $\mathrm{End}(M)$ by $f\mapsto gfg^{-1}$. From this description you can easily find a trivial submodule.